# How to connect multiple pipelines within the same Logstash instance running inside a docker container getting log messages from same filebeats port

Tags: docker, elasticsearch, logstash, kibana, elastic-stack

Currently we have a data stream in elasticsearch, lets call it "app_stream" in which we are ingesting log messages from an application "XMLTransformer" through FileBeats(port=5044) installed on the server where the application is running. We have a new scenario where now we are receiving log messages on the same FileBeats port 5044 from two different application running on the same server. Let's call another application "Model Server". Now log messages from both the XMLTransformer and Model Server are going into app_stream. According to the requirement, we are suppose to create a new data stream "ai_model_server" which will only have log messages from Model Server whereas app_stream will only have log_messages from XML transformer. Also, we want to create two separate logstash pipeline for XMLTransformer and Model Server which will ingest the log messages from the same Filebeats port 5044 and we do not want to make any changes on the filebeats. So, we are trying to implement the **[Pipeline-to-Pipeline Communication](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/current/pipeline-to-pipeline.html#pipeline-to-pipeline)** to route the messages from app_stream.conf pipeline to another ai_model_server.conf pipeline. But the logstash instance is running inside a docker container. How to get the Virtual Address which is available in docker container and use it in the logstash pipeline.

Comment: Have you thought about modifying the container's `ENTRYPOINT` so that it detects the IP and sets an ENV var, which you can then call from logstash config?

Comment: Are you sure the Docker network configuration is working as you expect?

Comment: @tomr  I have resolved the issue. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

I will be giving "modelserverlogs" literally as an virtual address in configuration as it can be user-defined (my confusion was whether I could give anything in place of the virtual address in the config or do I need to get the virtual IP addresses available in logstash docker container and use them in the config)

```
======================
app_stream.conf
======================
input {
beats {
port => 5044
type => beats
}
}
filter {
#XML transformer filter statements
add_tag => ["xml_transformer"]
}
output {
if "xml_transformer" in [tags] {
elasticsearch {
hosts => 0.0.0.0:0000
index => "app_stream"
}
}
else {
pipeline { send_to => modelserverlogs }
}
}

======================
ai_model_server.conf
=====================
input {
pipeline { address => modelserverlogs }
}
filter {
#modelserver log filter statements
}
output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => 0.0.0.0:0000
index => "ai_model_server"
}
}

=================
pipelines.yml
=================
-pipeline.id: app_stream
 path.config: "${LOGSTASH_BASE}/pipeline/app_stream.conf"
 queue.type: persisted
-pipeline.id: ai_model_server
 path.config: "${LOGSTASH_BASE}/pipeline/ai_model_server.conf"
 queue.type: persisted
```